# Winsorizing data in small sample

Tags: regression, linear-model, outliers, winsorizing

I have a relatively small sample of panel data (quarterly data for 68 firms over 7 years). My dependent variable is positively skewed. In order to limit the influence of observations with large values, I winsorize the data at the 99th percentile. I work with a simple linear model.

My issue is that:

- I do not find a significant effect of my main explanatory variable without winsorizing the dependent variable
- I find a slightly significant effect when winsorizing at the 99th percentile.
- I have an even higher significance of the main effect when winsorizing at the 95th percentile.

How can I convince myself that the main effect is indeed significant, knowing that it depends on how I winsorize the data?

Comment: Why winsorize at all? Perhaps something else such as working on logarithmic scale would be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you. My dependent variable includes zeros. I have worked with the transformation ln(1+x) and get slightly significant results for the main effect. The log transformation leads to a distribution for which mean and median are closer compared to the original distribution. When winsorizing the variable, the mean and median remain quite different. But then the question remains: which transformation should I trust? I know it's a complicated question, but I would like the advice of practitioners. On which parameters you base your decision in this case?

Comment: If you use a logarithmic link function zeros are not necessarily a problem. I don’t have enough information to suggest appropriate analyses.

Comment: What test are you using to judge 'significant effect'? Maybe there is an appropriate nonparametric test. // Are the outliers naturally occurring large values? Or do you think they are bad data? // Windsoring at 99th or 95th percentiles without also attending to 1st or 5th seems bound to create bias.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks a lot. I simply run an OLS model and take the t-stat to measure significance, what other tests do you have in mind? The outliers are not bad data, they are very big firms. I will check whether winsorizing at the 1st or 5th changes something.

Comment: @NickCox I will look at the logarithmic link function, are you referring to generalized linear models?

Comment: How about using Wilcoxon nonparametric test instead of t test?

Comment: You've said panel data, so the heading would be GEE rather than GLM, but that is what is what i was suggesting.